# Integrating GWT widget with vaadin 7

Tags: gwt, vaadin

I would like to integrate ganttchart GWT widget with vaadin7 application available at https://code.google.com/p/gwtgantt/

I went through some links which explores about integrating GWT widgets with vaadin7 but I don't think I understood.

Also, Do I need to write the connector and other stuff in vaadin to integrate GWT widgets? If yes then I am not quite sure what I will be writing in that.

Does anyone tried the same GWT widget with vaadin7 before?

Any pointers or Sample code will be really appreciated.

Regards,
Azhar

Answer (score 1):

When you are able to use Vaadin 7, this wiki article should help you to get started:
https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Integrating%20an%20existing%20GWT%20widget

I believe it handles exactly what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to write the server side code for GWT widgets, and extends the GWT widgets with the communication capability. Here a good project for you to get start with https://github.com/360-Innovations/VaadinSmartGWT

A little example (for Vaadin 6):

1 use eclipse with Vaadin plugin installed to create a Vaadin project then create Vaadin widget unpon that project, Vaadin plugin will generate all the nuts and bolts.

2 write the code
a client class wrapper for GanttChart It implements Paintable interface to communicate with server side

    `public class VGanttChart extends GanttChart implements Paintable {`

```
     public void paint(PaintTarget target) throws PaintException {

     }

     public void requestRepaint() {

     }

     ... ...

}
```

*for use of each methods, please look at the source comments at `Paintable.class`*
a server side corresponding class:

```
@ClientWidget(value = VGanttChart.class, loadStyle = LoadStyle.EAGER)
public class GanttChart extends AbstractComponent {

    public void paintContent(PaintTarget target) throws PaintException {

    }


    public void changeVariables(Object source, Map<String, Object> variables) {


    }

    ... ...
}
```

3 exporting as Vaadin Add-on Package, this is also provided by Vaadin plugin.

4 add the exported jar to your project /WEB-INF/lib, edit your XXXWidgetset.gwt.xml file by adding your add-on's widgetset like this:

`<inherits name="package path to your add-on's widgetset def file"/>`
 
if your widgetset def file is `myWidgetset.gwt.xml`, then the value for attribute name should be `"package path to widgetset"/myWidgetset`

5 Compile your Widgetset, this is also provided by Vaadin eclipse plugin, after compilation, new set of javascript, css, image resource was generated, now you can use your add-ons via the server side class.